# Ckan fails to render properly with custom theme and any URL route gives 404 error not found

Tags: web, assets, ckan

Facing a weird issue when setting up ckan locally after installing custom theme which causes improper rendering of CSS/HTML pages. I'm using Ckan 2.9.5 with debian 10 running inside docker with http://localhost:5000.
This is the screenshot of the problem:
[Assets/templates not loading/rendering](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YPqRK.png)

I tried changing ckan.root_url to custom path and also added nginx for routing based dataset or other urls. Tried docker system prune to remove all cache and volumes.